# Clicking the edit button on my Area 51 profile gives a server error page

Tags: bug, profile-page, area-51, 500-server-error, profile-edit

I click the edit button, and a request is made for `https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/edit/<my-user-id>`, and the server returns with an HTTP 302 redirect to `https://area51.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/edit/<my-user-id>`.

I'm not the only one who can repro.

Why is this happening? Please fix?

Comment: @AdamLear but if I'm giving it something else it gives 404, not 500 so assumed it does work. (I mean, when there's no internal error.)

Comment: I cannot even log in on Area 51.

Comment: Can confirm (though I can log in atleast). Any attempt to edit goes *boom*. On Area-51 Meta as well.